# Ошибка с PyQt5, как решить? (Pydroid 3)

Tags: python, android, pyqt5, pydroid

Ошибка на *Pydroid 3*. Не могу запустить скрипт выдает ошибку. 
Пересмотрел интернет особо ничего не нарыл. Как решить?

Сама ошибка:

> from PyQt5.QtCore import QDataStream
> ImportError: dlopen failed: library "libQt5Core.so" not found: needed by /data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so in namespace (default)

Comment: По моему опыту работы с Pydroid могу сказать, что скорее всего библиотека неправильно установилась. Попробуйте переустановить.

Comment: Не помогло. Попробовал.

Comment: Там вроде в pip несколько режимов установки, quick install и просто install. Попробуй разные.

Comment: линукс? поищите сами либы (в убунтоподобных  locate libQt5Core)

Comment: @SergeyTatarintsev, это никакой не линукс, программа для андроида. Просто построена видимо на базе линукса.

Comment: К тому же ковыряться в ней очень сложно, сам пробовал. Они какие-то свои модифицированные библиотеки используют.